# Econometrics-using log-log or continuously compounded annual rate of change

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, financial-economics

I am trying to run an econometric model, where I want to estimate the effect of credit growth on consumption growth, among other variables. 
Using data from Fred, I have the option of getting my variables as a continuously compounded annual rate of change. Are using these units and regressing normally the same as running a log-log regression?